# How can I close a bootstrap alert after a specific time using angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a bootstrap alert that appears after some operation is completed,but I want it to close after two or more seconds,how can I achieve this effect?I'm using Angular.js and I've only found solutions in jQuery.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Angular bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert) provides an option for [alert directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert) `dismiss-on-timeout`. It accepts timeout in milliseconds. This attribute requires the presence of the `close` attribute.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.show = true;
  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.show = false;
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
    <uib-alert type="danger" close="closeAlert()" ng-if="show" dismiss-on-timeout="4000">Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.</uib-alert>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok but what if I'm using the class alert-success of bootstrap? I have to change as you suggest or there is a way to use that class of alert?Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Change the type to `success`, `<uib-alert type="success" close="closeAlert()" dismiss-on-timeout="1000" />`

Comment: Ok,I've tried your solution,but the alert does not close after the time I'm expected it to.Why? In the callback I've written $scope.alert = null;

Comment: Solved using ng-if="condition"  in the markup and making that variable false inside the closeAlert method.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without writing anything in the function,the alert does not disappear automatically,don't know why.